# How to join two tables on a condition that may not occur?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

- Table User, has ID field
- Table Options, has userId , optionName, value

How to select users that have optionName = 'email' and value = 1 or have no entries for email in the Options table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from User u inner join Option o on u.id = o.userid
where (o.optionName = 'email' and o.value = 1) or (o.optionName <> 'email')
```

Answer (score 0):

THis might help you:

```
"SELECT * from users u left join options o on u.id = o.userid where (o.optionName = 'email' and o.value = 1) or o.userid is null; ";
```

Comment: Why `o.value!=0`? If there is value = 2 then it will fail as OP has clearly mentioned he wants `value=1`

Comment: I think I copied you query and did the edit. I will correct it now.